# How can I sync data between two databases?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, synchronization

I have to sync datas from google Fit server and our server.

In google Fit I have some datas like:

Steps:

- begin date
- end date
- value

etc.

I can have multiple values of this type, 9000 elements in my case.

I want to upload this values to my server. First time is simple, only copy all the values to my server.

But then I wand not to have the values double in server.

For doing that, I make:

- Download all the datas from my server
- Compare them with google fit values
- If begin date and end date is same then do nothing
- If not exist upload because this is a new value.

I omit in this case, the case where the value can be updated. Only if the value exist do nothing, if not exist create a new value.

That give for me:

for each google fit value
 for each my server value
Then do the test of value

The problem is the next: If I have 9000 values in google fit server, then 19000 values in my server. That give 9000 * 19000 = 171 000 000 of execution of the test. My web navigator crash. And it can be a lot of more values.

Have you a better idea?
Thansk

Comment: Why not use Google's server directly since you just update yours with the same data?

Comment: I need the datas in my server for many usages. Also to sync datas from others services as healthkit, and others...